# How to turn three 1D arrays into a 3D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to prepare data for marker on leaflet map my input is:

```
popup = ["abc", "bza", "ghh"];
myCol1 = [16.51545, 16.15454, 16.1454];
myCol2 = [80.2515, 80.1545, 80.5645];
```

What I need is this:

```
myData = [
    ["abc", 16.51545, 80.2515],
    ["bza", 16.15454, 80.1545],
    ["ghh", 16.1454, 80.5645]
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the arrays will always be the same length as eachother, a simple for loop would suffice:

```
var myData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < popup.length; i++) {
    myData.push([popup[i], myCol1[i], myCol2[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Just a pointer, if arrays are of different length, you should take max of array.length

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
popup.map((e, i) => [e, myCol1[i], myCol2[i]])
```

ES5 equivalent:

```
popup.map(function(element, index) {
    return [element, myCol1[index], myCol2[index]];
});
```

```js
var popup = ["abc", "bza", "ghh"],
    myCol1 = [16.51545, 16.15454, 16.1454],
    myCol2 = [80.2515, 80.1545, 80.5645];

var data = popup.map((e, i) => [e, myCol1[i], myCol2[i]]);
console.log(data);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: I'm not sure how safe it is to answer a question using lambda expressions (just for the sake of brevity) without an explanation...

Comment: @JonathanBrooks Arrow functions are perfectly fine. I've also added equivalent ES5 code for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and
[`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
 nested:

```js
var popup = ["abc", "bza", "ghh"],
    myCol1 = [16.51545, 16.15454, 16.1454],
    myCol2 = [80.2515, 80.1545, 80.5645],
    myData = [popup, myCol1, myCol2].reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            r[j] = r[j] || [];
            r[j][i] = b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myData, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```